# Sharepoint and Linq rounding

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list with sales figures for months.  There are three columns I am using month, year and sales.  I am trying to write a webservice to group the data into sales by month and export that as xml.  In sharepoint the sales figures for 2010 have 2 decimal places, for 2011 and 2012 they are integers.  When I run the following linq query it gives me the correct sums for 2010 and 2011 but for 2012 it rounds the numbers to the nearest million.

```
var query = from row in SPListDT.AsEnumerable()
group row by new
{
    year = row.Field<double>("Year"),
    month = row.Field<string>("Month")
} into grp
orderby grp.Key.year, grp.Key.month
select new
{
    Key = grp.Key,
    year = grp.Key.year,
    month = grp.Key.month,
    budgetSum =grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Sales"))
};
```

Sharepoint seems to only to have one data type for numbers (numbers) which with this method returns a double.  I have used the webservice to only kick back all the  numbers it gets and they all are right for every year.  Why is it rounding only for some of the data?

Comment: Turns out I had everything right after all. The data was actually sales projections and even though the numbers looked random for a month when summed they would equal an even million (eg 441,000,000).